# How to modify html element with jQuery generated from ajax?

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I have a text field and if user type something in it, I want to show suggestion of names with ajax then user will select any name that will be set in the text field then user can submit the form.....

```
<form>
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" value="" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

here is the form.... guess after getting the response from ajax I displayed the suggestion in a div then if user select/click any name that name will be in the value of the text field.... but the problem is when I display the name then I can't access it later with jQuery.... any help??

```
<div class="ajax-response">
    <p>Name 1</p>
    <p>Name 2</p>
    <p>Name 3</p>
    more like this.........
</div>
```

Comment: How about an autocomplete plugin like http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/?

Comment: bro there will be a massive name... I need ajax to get name from database....

Comment: @BlackReaper The jQuery UI autocomplete plugin supports using a server-side data source (see "Remote datasource" in the documentation), so you'd still be able to query your database for the list of names.

Comment: For that I need to load another Library if it is possible with jQuery then I would not add UI Library :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a div element with a class of `ajax-response` that contains a series of p elements that have text which is your names. The easiest solution would be to delegate an event handler to p elements inside `div.ajax-response`, like so:

```
$('div.ajax-response').on('click', 'p', function(e) {
    // one of your names was clicked on
    $('#name').val($(this).text()); // set the value of your #name input to be the text of the clicked element
});
```

Note that this requires the same `.ajax-response` element to always exist on your page, and the code would need to be called at a point when that element exists in the DOM (e.g. from a DOM ready handler).

Comment: Bro I added the name in div.ajax-response with jquery and the dom is not reloaded. like this =  $('div.ajax-response').html(response); now will it find the 'p'?? It's not working in my case.... Can you tell me more??

Comment: @BlackReaper Have you put the code I provided inside a document ready handler? http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. After you add the response to the document you can do stuff like:

```
$('.ajax-response p').click(function(ev) {
    var clickedEl = $(ev.currentTarget); 
    // do stuff
});
```

Comment: inspect DOM structure after adding the response. Then paste it here.
You should do that click handler *after* adding!

Comment: That was my problem... don't know how to inspect DOM structure... can you tell me the method??

Comment: assuming Windows, press Ctrl+Shift+C (or F12)